# Comparison of experimental method against gold standard?

Tags: r, paired-data, agreement-statistics, concordance

I have a method X, assumed to be the gold standard. Then, I have a method Y. The response variable (for example, weight) is a continuous variable. For a sample of **n** individuals, the response variable is measured with method X and also, **k** raters measure each individuals' weight using method Y.

How can I determine if method Y shows high concordance with method X? How to test If *Y* presents statistically significant differences with method X, whether it under or overestimates the outcome variable?

Comment: What is the role of the $k$ raters. Is the measurement dependend on the rater? Could there be raters who tend to measure high or low or do $k$ raters simply reflex $k$ independent measurements?

Comment: Yes, indeed. The presence of k raters is because we want to test the precision of the second method. There could exist a bias because of the rater too. Some raters can measure high while other can measure low.